# PHP return messy characters after calling fsockopen

Tags: php, fsockopen

I met with a PHP messy characters issue. Although it maybe a simple or basic question, it hasn't been solved until now after hours googling. I run the following simple snippet to access an unreachable IP, and echo `$errstr`.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$socket = fsockopen("10.180.100.100", "23", $errno, $errstr, 3);// IP which can't access
echo $errstr."<br/>";
echo mb_detect_encoding($errstr)."<br/>";
```

When I run it from PHP CLI, the result is what I expect.
[image]

When I access it from my Apache server, I get messy characters.
[image]

I have set `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8")`, and set page encoding as UTF-8. Neither is helpful.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Messy :) Thats UTF-8 characters most likely

Comment: Make sure that the `encoding_test.php` code file is also UTF-8 encoded and you will see UnMessy text

Comment: And in Apache start the page with `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>`

Comment: I don't get the same thing, of course I don't have whatever generates that debug table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The file is encoded as UTF-8. I use vscode and can see it clearly. I have added the code you provided, but not helpful.

Comment: Read the rest of the DUP then, somewhere in there is somethng that will help

Comment: @AbraCadaver So it maybe an enviroment issue. But I still don't know how to resolve.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you. I will read it immediately.